# What means her ride didn't show?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I just heard this in a video and the sentence goes like this:

> Her ride didn't show.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that she had called for an Uber or a Taxi but they did not show up to pick her up. Or may be she called a friend to come give her a ride, and her friend did not show up.

From Cambridge, a ride (n)

> a person who gives you a ride in their car

Answer (score 2):

> Her ride didn't show.

This is a less common variant of the following:

> Her ride didn't ***show up***.

---

From the definition of the intransitive sense of the verbal phrase [**show up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20up):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    **1 a** : ARRIVE, APPEAR
>   // *showed up* late for his own wedding
>   // Hundreds of tourists *showed up*, wearing bright sweaters, even though it was warm.
>   — Tony Earley

---

In other words, *her ride didn't show* means *her ride didn't arrive*.

When speaking, we often drop prepositions, but we understand they are assumed to be there.